# Confusion in the proof of the derivative of $u(x)/v(x)?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm reading Hairer/Wanner's: *Analysis by Its history*. I'm in trouble to understand this:

> $\;$ [image]

I don't understand why:

$$\frac{v\Delta u - u \Delta v}{v^2+v\Delta v}=\frac{v\Delta u - u \Delta v}{v^2}\cdot \left(1- \frac{\Delta v}{v}+ \frac{\Delta v^2}{v^2}\pm \dots \right)$$

I tried to do the following:

$$\frac{ (\text{$\Delta $u} v-\text{$\Delta $v} u)}{v^2+\text{$\Delta $v}
   v}x=\frac{\text{$\Delta $u} v-\text{$\Delta $v} u}{v^2}$$

And solving for $x$ yields:

$$x=\frac{v+\Delta v}{v}$$

And then I guess that:

$$\frac{v+\Delta v}{v}\stackrel{?}{=}\left(1- \frac{\Delta v}{v}+ \frac{\Delta v^2}{v^2}\pm \dots \right)$$

I know that I should apply the formula for the geometric series here as the author says, but my doubt is that the author says that we should use the geometric series for $(1+\Delta v/v)^{-1}$, then is

$$\left[ \frac{v+\Delta v}{v}\right] \stackrel{?}{=}\left[  \left( \frac{v+\Delta v}{v} \right)^{-1}=\frac{v}{v+\Delta v}\right]$$

Comment: That title is a mess of the meaningless.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. I fixed the title (is it better?). Sometimes I forget that the context I have in mind isn't shared by others, sorry for that.

Comment: But even the last line is nonsensical. What does it mean for $A\stackrel{?}=[B=C]$? What do the square brackets on the right do?  It means nothing to put square brackets in like that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I meant to say that I know that $B=C$, but I don't know if $A=B$ (which would also imply that A=C).

Comment: Basically, you are asking the wrong question, in both the title and the end of this question. I have no idea why you think this has anything to do with the title of the question - you've already made a numerical error - the $x$ should be on the right.

Comment: Basically, your real question is the first line after the image: "Why is...," but you've made an erroneous deduction which has led you to ask about some falsehood.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. I was aware of the hazard these assumptions could cause, but it was the only too I had.

Comment: You mean you couldn't ask the question you actually had? Like: "Confused by step in proof of derivative of $\frac{u}{v}$"?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I usually prefer to show that I tried to do something. But sometimes, this alters the question (just as in this case) to something meaningless/wrong.

Comment: Showing work is good, putting work in the title is pointless. What question are you trying to solve? Put that in your title.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I put something more meaningful now. Your answer already answers my question, but I want to practice on making a nicer title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that:

$$\frac{1}{v^2+v\Delta v} = \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\Delta v}{v}}$$

and:

$$\frac{1}{1+w} = 1-w+w^2-\cdots$$

when $|w|<1$. So setting $w=\frac{\Delta v}{v}$ you get:

$$\frac{1}{v^2+v\Delta v} = \frac{1}{v^2}\left(1-\frac{\Delta v}{v} + \left(\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right)^3 +\cdots \right)$$

The numerator $v\Delta u -u\Delta v$ is irrelevant to this step.

You've put the $x$ on the wrong side of the equation. (Probably shouldn't use $x$, but whatever.) The conclusion in the proof is that:

$$\frac{v\Delta u-u\Delta v}{v^2+v\Delta v} = \frac{v\Delta u-u\Delta v}{v^2} X$$ for some $X$, and that this $$X=1-\frac{\Delta v}{v}+\dots$$

So you've put $X$ on the wrong side, which is why you are getting that somehow the proof needs $\frac{v+\Delta v}{v}=\frac{v}{v+\Delta v}$.